# Kinesis Data Stream triggers Lambda with same sequence id

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I have the below setup:

DynamoDB -> Kinesis Data Stream -> Triggers Lambda function

I see that each record in Kinesis Data Stream invokes the lambda function multiple times (atleast twice). I see that there are atleast two lambda different invocations with the same event id, shard and sequence ids.

I only find documentation on dealing with duplicate records. I already have some logic in place to take care of duplicate records, but I want to reduce the number of unnecessary lambda invocations to reduce cost. Could someone please point me to a solution to this? I'm new to Kinesis so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here

Comment: Does your lambda throw any errors or time out? Are partial failures of batch splitting enabled on the mapping?

Comment: Lambda does not time out, it continues to process data all the times lambda is triggered. And yes batch splitting is enabled, but it wouldn't split right? Since the lambda successfully processes records every time

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "continues to process data"? A single lambda invocation can return successfully, throw an exception or time out. Which one of the three is happening? You can tell it by looking in the CloudWatch logs

Comment: Sorry, I meant that all lambda invocations return successfully